# DockPanel Suite's Float Window minimum size & location property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, dockpanel-suite

I tried to modify [source file](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite) (winFormsUI ->Docking ->Floatwindow.cs[design])
here i set minimum size property of the window to (100,100)
built & used the dll in my project. below is the code for calling child form in dockpanel.

```
ChildForm.Show(dockPanel1, DockState.Float);
```

yet i can resize float window [DockContent/ Child Form] below (100,100)

1) what else should i change to set minimum size for float window ? 
2) is there a way to set position for float window? by default, it shows up at left top.
 can we make it appear at center of screen?

Answer (score 0):

We have used GitHub to generate live FAQ, https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues?q=label%3A%22faq+candidate%22+is%3Aclosed

[#56](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/56) should have answered your question.

> I had to keep this.Pane.FloatWindow.Size in the settings.

Comment: sorry for delay in my response, can you provide some other source or example?  i didn't find much from the above link